# Show filename and grep match

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have multiple text files with headers in the below format

NB:The content varies this is just a sample content

```
200 OK
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=631138520; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 01 Jul 2020 17:33:00 GMT
Set-Cookie:user_prefs=EYPs6Cogk25-Nn-iab9nopnNRhVjZACCuD8nzsDoaKXQYBclnbzSnBwdpdQ83dCgJR0lEAPWMYJQuIhYBgA.; expires=Thu, 01-Jul-2021 17:33:00 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; domain=.example.com fve=1593624780.0; expires=Sun, 01-Aug-2021 09:51:20 GMT; Max-Age=34186700; path=/; domain=.example.com; secure exp_hangover=aWyK4rZnvZOB6FIBeH6OrEa_8s1jZACCuD8nzsDoaqXy1KT4xKKSzLTM5MzEnPicxJLUvOTK-EKTeCMDQ0slK6XMvNSczPTMpJxUpVoGAA..; expires=Tue, 29-Sep-2020 17:33:00 GMT; Max-Age=7776000; path=/; domain=.example.com; secure; HttpOnly last_browse_page=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fshop%2Fbrinandbell; path=/; domain=.example.com
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: c49da5740469ce162a69fd7396adced7/17684619190655032818;o=0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: frame-ancestors 'self'; 
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block; 
X-Recruiting: Is code your craft? https://www.example.com/careers
Retry-Count: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
```

I want to show filenames and its contents matching my expression for example "200 OK"
I tried `more * | cat | grep -wE "200 OK"`
The above command is showing the expression only without displaying the filename and its contents.

Expected output

```
filename.txt

200 OK
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=631138520; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 01 Jul 2020 17:33:00 GMT
Set-Cookie:user_prefs=EYPs6Cogk25-Nn-iab9nopnNRhVjZACCuD8nzsDoaKXQYBclnbzSnBwdpdQ83dCgJR0lEAPWMYJQuIhYBgA.; expires=Thu, 01-Jul-2021 17:33:00 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; domain=.example.com fve=1593624780.0; expires=Sun, 01-Aug-2021 09:51:20 GMT; Max-Age=34186700; path=/; domain=.example.com; secure exp_hangover=aWyK4rZnvZOB6FIBeH6OrEa_8s1jZACCuD8nzsDoaqXy1KT4xKKSzLTM5MzEnPicxJLUvOTK-EKTeCMDQ0slK6XMvNSczPTMpJxUpVoGAA..; expires=Tue, 29-Sep-2020 17:33:00 GMT; Max-Age=7776000; path=/; domain=.example.com; secure; HttpOnly last_browse_page=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fshop%2Fbrinandbell; path=/; domain=.example.com
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: c49da5740469ce162a69fd7396adced7/17684619190655032818;o=0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: frame-ancestors 'self'; 
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block; 
X-Recruiting: Is code your craft? https://www.example.com/careers
Retry-Count: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: i have updated the output within the question

Comment: Is `200 OK` always on first line?

Comment: no it will change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify the searched word and dir:
`for i in $(grep -ilR "200 OK" *);do echo $i; cat $i;done`

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `bash` script with `grep` producing matching filenames:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
    printf '%s\n\n' "$file"
    cat "$file"
done < <(grep -ZlxF '200 OK' *.txt)
```

Comment: Wouldn't be `-x` safer than `-w` here?

Comment: I had `-x` originally but sometimes these `curl` like outputs have DOS line ending or `\r` embedded

Comment: its saying ```line 2: file: No such file or directory``` , and it is not displaying the content

Comment: Are you getting filenames using `grep -ZlwF '200 OK' *.txt` command?

Comment: yes , I am getting filename , I got the answer which is more compact

Comment: You can chose whatever answer you like but running a `for` loop over filenames is buggy and is highly discouraged. Filenames may contain spaces and wildcards.

Comment: @anubhava : Right! But in this case, i would run a `dos2unix` on the curl'ed files, because the \r endings will otherwise bite you sooner or later - for instance, inside your `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using only grep.

```
grep -rnw . -e "searchKey"
```

From MAN page

- -r, --recursive - recursively search the directory
- -n, --line-number - print line number with output lines
- -w, --word-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole words
- **.** - replace with directory

Comment: I got he file name , but i needed the content too . But this is a compact answer for finding the filename , I am upvoting for that

Answer (score 1):

Why do you try to concatenate the files with `more` and `grep` afterwards? You could simply do `grep -HEw 'OK 200' *`. True, then the filename would be a prefix in front of every line (instead of being displayed once at the beginning), but that would be easy to strip when processing the result further (I suppose you will do further processing :-).

Responding to comment:
You can do `grep -HEw -A 17 'OK 200' *` to see the 17 lines afterwards, too. Put in a big enough number if you want to see all lines of the file. Note that all lines will be prefixed with the filename.

Comment: I got he file name , but i needed the content too . But this is a compact answer for finding the filename , I am upvoting for that